# How to define template inside a template class?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, eigen

I can find template definition for matrixes: `Eigen::Matrix<T,4,5> v;` https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html . However, I could not find for the vectors. Hence, I want to define a similar way for vectors but inside a template class, i.e., `EigenVector` as the same type T of its class as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class HagenDWT
{
 public:
   template <typename T, int Size> using EigenVector = Eigen::Matrix<T, Size, 1>;
   //rest of the code
 private:

 };
```

However, if I define `EigenVector` as:

```
template <typename M, int Size> using EigenVector = Eigen::Matrix<T, Size, 1>;
```

Everything works fine. I want to define `EigenVector` the same as its class type T. If it is possible could you suggest what to change?

Comment: If you won't want to parametrized the alias over `typename M`, why add it as a template parameter? Just use `template <int Size>`.

Comment: Since the outer class has a `T` template parameter, if you want the inner template to use the same type then you don't need to include another `T` parameter in the inner template: `template <int Size> using EigenVector = Eigen::Matrix<T, Size, 1>;` Otherwise, if you want the inner template to use a different type then ignore `T` and use `M` instead: `template <typename M, int Size> using EigenVector = Eigen::Matrix<M, Size, 1>;`

Comment: ... and if you want it to use `T` as default but with the option to supply a different type: `template <int Size, typename M = T> using EigenVector = Eigen::Matrix<M, Size, 1>;`

Comment: Thank you everyone, those comments were really helpful , yep it's working now

Comment: Should this be closed? It's odd because the question answers itself: "*Everything works fine."* There was just a non-realization that `EigenVector` was already defined to be over the same `T` as its class, as desired, plus an unused `M` parameter.